# Sending Facebook user data to server fails - Android

Tags: android, mysql, facebook, http-post, facebook-login

I have an app with a facebook login (4.2), when the user logs in, I pass his data (name, birthday, etc) to my MySql online database. My problem is that on some devices I get empty strings, and I can't figure out why?

The user data is sent to the server in the onCompleted() method, inside onSucces() after it is saved to preferences:

```
public class SplashActivity extends Activity {

    private LoginButton loginButton;
    CallbackManager callbackManager;
    private Editor editor;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR);
        getActionBar().hide();
        setContentView(R.layout.splash);

        FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
        callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();

        loginButton = (LoginButton) findViewById(R.id.login_button);
        loginButton.setReadPermissions(Arrays.asList("public_profile, email, user_birthday, user_friends"));

        editor = this.getSharedPreferences("UserInfo", Context.MODE_PRIVATE).edit();

        isLoggedIn();


        if (isLoggedIn()) {
            loginButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            new CountDownTimer(3000, 5000) {
                public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                }

                public void onFinish() {
                    finish();
                }

            }.start();
        } else {

        }


        // Callback registration
        loginButton.registerCallback(callbackManager,
                new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
                        // App code
                        GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(
                                loginResult.getAccessToken(),
                                new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {                                
                                    @Override
                                    public void onCompleted(JSONObject object, GraphResponse response) {                                        
                                        try {

                                            String id = (String) object.get("id");
                                            String name = (String) object.get("name");
                                            String email = (String) object.get("email");
                                            String birthday = (String) object.get("birthday");

                                            editor.putString("id", id);
                                            editor.putString("name", name);
                                            editor.putString("email", email);
                                            editor.putString("birthday", birthday);

                                            editor.commit();

                                            SendUserInfo sender = new SendUserInfo(getApplication());
                                            sender.sendUserInfo();

                                        } catch (JSONException e) {                                         
                                            e.printStackTrace();
                                        }

                                    }
                                });
                        Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
                        parameters.putString("fields", "id,name, email, gender, birthday");
                        request.setParameters(parameters);
                        request.executeAsync();

                        finish();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancel() {
                        // App code
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(FacebookException exception) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplication(),
                                "Va rugam sa incercati mai tarziu.",
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                });

    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }

    public boolean isLoggedIn() {
        AccessToken accessToken = AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken();
        return accessToken != null;
    }

}
```

Class to upload the data:

```
public class SendUserInfo {

    Context context;
    private int refCode; 

    public SendUserInfo(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

public void sendUserInfo () {

        SharedPreferences preferences = context.getSharedPreferences("UserInfo",
                Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        String regId = preferences.getString("userRegId", null);
        String id = preferences.getString("id", "null");
        String name = preferences.getString("name", null);
        String email = preferences.getString("email", null);
        String birthday = preferences.getString("birthday", null);


        Random r = new Random();
        refCode = r.nextInt(9000 - 6000) + 456;     


        final int DEFAULT_TIMEOUT = 10000;
        AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();
        client.setTimeout(DEFAULT_TIMEOUT);

        RequestParams params = new RequestParams();      
        params.put("regId", regId); 
        params.put("fbId", id);
        params.put("name", name); 
        params.put("email", email); 
        params.put("birthday", birthday); 
        params.put("refCode", String.valueOf(refCode)); 



        client.post("http://www.edmondvarga.com/laborator/save-user-info.php",
                params, new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {

                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(int arg0, Header[] arg1, byte[] arg2,
                            Throwable arg3) {
                        sendUserInfo();

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(int arg0, Header[] arg1, byte[] arg2) {

                    }
                });

    }


}
```

Comment: Some users may not have valid emails or birthdays (even if they give you permission), so you always need to handle empty fields. The only guarantee you'll get is a unique ID per user.

Comment: @MingLi please add this as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some users may not have valid emails or birthdays (even if they give you permission), so you always need to handle empty fields. The only guarantee you'll get is a unique ID per user.